# Customize the Server Explorer properties in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to customize the properties listed in the Properties window in Visual Studio for Server Explorer?  Specifically, I would like to be able to see the column description for tables in SQL Server.

Here's a screenshot of the properties window from Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition:

[image]

And here's a portion of the same field's properties from the SQL Server Management Studio window:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is an option that is available by configuring VS, but you could probably look at the Visual Studio SDK (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138565.aspx) and SQL Server Management Objects (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms162169.aspx). Whether it would be worth the effort is the question...

Comment: That's the early conclusion I came to as well through a bit of Googling.  I was hoping there would be some straightforward configuration and that it was just buried in some XML file and that's why I couldn't find it in the UI.  And, no, I don't think it would be worth the effort to extend VS for this if that's the only option.